# R English Language Dictionary containing definitions

Tags: r

I am looking for a package in R that contains the english dictionary.  When I google around all I find are packages that have a "dictionary" class, but what I want is something that already has all of the definitions included so I can enter a string and extract a definition.  Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try looking at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

With respect to extracting definition a partial solution could involve making use of the [WikipediR](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/WikipediR/index.html) package.

```
require(WikipediR)
phrs <- c("car","house")
j <- 1
for (i in phrs) {
    pgs[j] <- page_content("en", "wikipedia", page_name = i, as_wikitext = TRUE)
    j <- j + 1
}
```

You could then later extract relevant parts of the sourced pages.As Wikipedia pages are formatted in a more or less consistent manner you would have to fish out one of the first paragraphs that hopefully would correspond to something that can be considered as dictionary definition.

## Edit

> I am looking for a package in R that contains the english dictionary.
>   When I google around all I find are packages that have a "dictionary"
>   class

You mentioned a *dictionary class*. In **R**:

> Many R objects have a class attribute, a character vector giving the
>   names of the classes from which the object inherits

as [defined](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/class.html) in the documentation. I'm guessing that you are not interested in actual *classes* but in a linguistic definition of a word.